# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user '2506679_erp'@'%' to database '

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Facing this problem

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user '2506679_erp'@'%' to database '2506673_erp' in /srv/disk15/2506679/www/iieerp.tk/web/dbh.php on line 6

```
<?php 
  define('DB_SERVER', 'fdb6.atspace.me'); 
  define('DB_USERNAME', '2506679_erp**'); 
  define('DB_PASSWORD', '******'); define('DB_DATABASE', '2506673_erp'); 
  $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE‌​);
?>
```

Hosting website is ATSPACE.com

Comment: <?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'fdb6.atspace.me');
   define('DB_USERNAME', '2506679_erp');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'A@123456');
   define('DB_DATABASE', '2506673_erp');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>

Comment: http://iieerp.tk

Comment: Isn't this a case where a careful reading of the error message will diagnose the problem for you? `Access denied for 'someUser'` actually means you didn't provide a valid username or password when you invoked `mysqli_connect()`, **DANGER: do not provide live usernames and passwords in Stack Overflow questions.. Change that password NOW to something secret.**  You can't get rid of a password in SO by editing a question: previous versions of the question are always visible.

Comment: Thank you @O.Jones

Comment: please tell where to find username in atspace.com @O.Jones